# Как обеспечить удаление содержимого первой кнопки из чата после нажатия на вторую кнопку? aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Я создаю свой магазин-бот в телеграмме. У меня имеется несколько таблиц в базе данных с названиями разделов меню, откуда берутся товары: menu,drinks,other.Нажимая на инлайн кнопки в главном меню мы открываем разные разделы меню.При нажатии на кнопку с названием раздела меню бот отправляет все товары которые относятся к этому разделу меню. Хотелось сделать так чтобы после нажатия на любую вторую кнопку, "содержимое"отправленное при нажатии первой кнопки удалялось из чата и так по кругу при каждом новом нажатии.

*буду рад любой помощи*

```
async def sql_read2(table):
    return cur.execute("SELECT * FROM "+table).fetchall()



#функция из подсчета кол-ва товаров в таблице
async def sql_count_items(table):
    count=0
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM '+table).fetchall():
        count+=1
    return count

#функция отправки разделов меню
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startswith='choice_'),state="*")
async def obrabot_category(callback_query:types.CallbackQuery,state:FSMContext):
    global prev_table
    count_to_del=0
    if not callback_query.data=='choice_back' or "choice_basket":
        if prev_table:
                count_to_del=await sqlite_db.sql_count_items(prev_table)
                mes_id=callback_query.message.message_id
                try:
                    for i in range(0,count_to_del,1):
                        await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id,prev_table)
                        if i!=count_to_del:
                            await bot.delete_message(callback_query.message.chat.id,mes_id+i+1)

                        if i==count_to_del:
                            await bot.delete_message(callback_query.message.chat.id,mes_id+i)
                            return
                except Exception:
                    await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id,mes_id)


    if callback_query.data=="choice_back":
        await bot.delete_message(callback_query.message.chat.id,callback_query.message.message_id)
        await FSMCustomer.start_purchase.set()
        await wellcome(callback_query,state)
        return
    if callback_query.data=="choice_basket":
        await FSMCustomer.show_basket.set()
        await show_basket(callback_query,state)
        return
    await FSMCustomer.basket.set()
    table=callback_query.data[7:]
    read = await sqlite_db.sql_read2(table)
    for ret in read:
        await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, ret[0],
                                         f"<b>{ret[1]}</b>\n<i>{ret[2]}</i>\nЦена {ret[-1]} руб", parse_mode="html",
                                         reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                                             InlineKeyboardButton(f"Выбрать {ret[1]}",
                                                                  callback_data=f"pizza_{ret[1]}_{ret[-1]}")))
    prev_table=callback_query.data.split("_")[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу 2 варианта

1. Создать стек и там сохранять сообщения, которые ты отправлял.
2. Воспользоваться библиотекой [aiogram_dialog](https://github.com/Tishka17/aiogram_dialog). По дефолту при
   переключении между окнами будут удаляться предыдущие кнопки и
   редактироваться/создаваться новое.